# The reasons why rps procedure use spinlock with local_irq_disable

Tags: network-programming, kernel, interrupt, spinlock, softirq

These days, I'm studying **kernel internal network code**, especially **RPS** code. You know, there are a lot of functions about that. But I am focusing on some functions about **SMP queue processing** such as `enqueue_to_backlog` and `process_backlog`.

**I wonder about synchronization btw two cores(or single core) by using two functions -`enqueue_to_backlog` and `process_backlog`-.**

In that functions, **A core(A) holds a `spin_lock` of the other core(B) for queueing packets into `input_pkt_queue` and scheduling napi of the core(B)**. And **A Core(B) also holds a `spin_lock` for splicing `input_pkt_queue` to `process_queue` of the core(B) and removing napi schedule by itself.** I know that `spin_lock` should be held to prevent two core from accessing the same queue each other during processing queue.

**But I can't understand why `spin_lock` is called with `local_irq_disable`(or `local_irq_save`). I think that there is no accessing the queues or `rps_lock` of the core(B) by Interrupts Context(TH), when interrupts(TH) preempt current context(softirq, BH).** - Of course, napi struct can be accessed for scheduling napi by TH, but it holds disabling irq until queueing packet- *So I wonder about why `spin_lock` is called with irq disable.*

**I think it is impossible to preempt current context(napi, softirq) by other BH such as tasklet. Is it true? And I want to know whether local_irq_disable disable all cores irq or just current core's irq literally?** Actually, I read a book about kernel development, but I think i don't understand preemption enough.

**Would explain the reasons why rps procedure use `spin_lock` with `local_irq_disable`?**

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6556013/1076479

Comment: I read it. It is really helpful but the question still remains. Even though there is no `rps_lock` on TH,  the functions - `enqueue_to_backlog` and `process_backlog` - try to `rps_lock` with irq disable. May this way get some performance gain? To avoid a delayed timespan of busy waiting by preemption of irq on a core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling interrupts affects the current core (only). When disabled, therefore, no other code *on the same core* will be able to interfere with an update to a data structure. The point of spinlocks is to extend the "lock-out" to other cores (although it's cooperative, not hardware-enforced).

It's dangerous/irresponsible to take a spin lock in the kernel *without* disabling interrupts because, when an interrupt then occurs, the current code will be suspended, and now you are preventing other cores from making progress while some *unrelated* interrupt handler is running (even if another user process or tasklet on the original core won't be able to preempt). Other cores might be in an interrupt or BH context themselves and now you're delaying the entire system. Spin locks are supposed to be held for very brief periods to do critical updates to shared data structures.

It's also a good way to generate deadlocks. Consider if the scenario above were replicated in another subsystem (or possibly another device in the same subsystem, but I'll describe the former).

Here, core A takes a spinlock in subsystem 1 without disabling interrupts. At the same time, core B takes a spinlock in subsystem 2 also without disabling interrupts. Now what happens if an interrupt related to subsystem 2 happens on core A, and while executing the subsystem 2 interrupt handler, core A needs to update a structure protected by the spinlock held in core B. But at about the same time, a subsystem 1 interrupt happens on core B, which needs to update a data structure in that subsystem. Now both cores are busy-waiting for a spinlock held by the other core, and the entire system is frozen until you do a hard reset.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got it. Here is one more question, Gil Hamilton. What kinds of context can preempt another context? Is there priority btw contexts -TH, BH, Process and so on -? For example, Could softirq(ex. napi) context be preempted by Tasklet? And also, could process context be preempted by BH ? Regards.