# what happens if Interrupt occur after mutex lock has been acquired, and interrupt handler also has mutex lock with same resource?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, linux-device-driver

I am new to Linux device driver programing, please help me out.

I was doing some little experiment, then i came with strange output.
For some reasons i have kept **mutex_lock(system)** in interrupt handler. In other function (let us call func1) i have kept **mutex_lock(system)**. While executing func1, before **mutex_unlock(system)** interrupt is occurring. So theoretically dead lock should occur. But its not happening.

I want to know how exactly its working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linux Kernel Preemption during spin\_lock and mutex\_lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555358/linux-kernel-preemption-during-spin-lock-and-mutex-lock)

Comment: mutex may not be used in IRQ context. The exception when IRQ is threaded (usually in RT environment), in that case it's acting like a normal lock, i.e. *first takes — first uses*.

Comment: @stark, Thanks for the response, No it didn't, My question is "when an interrupt occurs while executing func1 after mutex_lock(system) and before mutex_unlock(system), interrupt handler will be called. But  my interrupt handler also have mutex_lock(system). So theoretically dead_lock should happen. But its not happening in my case. Is there any idea why dead lock is not happening???"

Comment: @0andriy, Thanks for the response, I was doing some experiment(Just to understand the behavior). I used lock in interrupt handler function so a dead lock should occur, but its not happening. Why?

Comment: I believe mutex_lock calls preempt_disable

Comment: When asking such question, try to enable all relevant `CONFIG_DEBUG_*` options in the kernel configuration. You will be surprised.